# Python: pip can't find setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

How can I direct pip to find `setup.py`?  My `setup.py` file is located `~/setuptools-3.5.1`.

I ran

```
dustin@dustin:~$ python setuptools-3.5.1/setup.py egg_info
running egg_info
writing requirements to setuptools.egg-info/requires.txt
writing setuptools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to setuptools.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to setuptools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to setuptools.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'setuptools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'setuptools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
dustin@dustin:~$
```

so it looks as everything is okay, but when I run pip, I get

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/matplotlib
Storing debug log for failure in /home/dustin/.pip/pip.log
```

I am under the impression that when I run pip it isn't finding `setup.py`

Comment: the "what I want" part is important. It should be a package with a setup.py at the top level.

Comment: No, but `matplotlib` would have to be a pip-installable package. Is it?

Comment: I know, I have had similar problems before. But I am not sure it is pip installable. I've had to go through all kinds of loops in the past to work with many versions of matplotlib.

Comment: What does `/home/dustin/.pip/pip.log` say?

Comment: It looks like you are missing `freetype` or `freetype2` on your sysyem.

Comment: I added answer with the relevant part of the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib` has many external dependencies. Some of these are required. You can see the list of required ones in the log file produced by the attempted `pip install`. In your case, it is this:

```
REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.8.1]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 3.2.1]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [pkg-config information for 'freetype2' could
                        not be found.]
                   png: yes [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                        be found. Using unknown version.]
```

also

```
============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
============================================================================
```

Here, you can see that `freetype` couldn't be found. You need to install it on your system.

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to the directory that contains your setup.py and run:

```
pip install -e .
```

Comment: You don't need the `-e`.

Comment: Navigating to the directory where `setup.py` is and then trying to install doesn't work.  It produces the same error.

Comment: `ls -lah` - are your permissions correct for the user you are installing as?

Comment: `-rw-rw-rw-  1 dustin dustin 8.2K Apr  7 19:07 setup.py
drwxrwxr-x  4 dustin dustin 4.0K May  7 16:26 setuptools
drwxrwxr-x  2 dustin dustin 4.0K May  7 16:20 setuptools.egg-info
drwxrwxr-x  3 dustin dustin 4.0K May  7 16:20 tests
`

Comment: is this in a virtualenv or are you sudo installing the package?

Comment: I am `sudo` installing

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. This is probably because some of the dependencies may not be installed. Solved this by installing using package manager in ubuntu. Use the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the directory that contains your setup.py and run:

pip install -e .

this worked for me. But still i got the massage setup.py not found when i used "pip install -e '.[all]' " in the anaconda environment terminal.
Instead i used "pip install gym[all]" and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was related to  "File 'setup.py' not found.", but I did not expect it to find `setup.py`, and the issue was fixed when I updated [pip to a version (>21.3) that could use `pyproject.toml` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711606/how-to-install-a-package-using-pip-in-editable-mode-with-pyproject-toml#comment126329840_69711730)

For me the project ([arelle](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle)) does not have a setup.py file.  That's because arelle uses [`pyproject.toml` file instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983756/what-is-pyproject-toml-file-for).

So I ***expected*** setup.py would not be found. **But I didn't know why `pip` couldn't use `pyproject.toml` instead.**

I learned from [a StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711606/how-to-install-a-package-using-pip-in-editable-mode-with-pyproject-toml#comment126329840_69711730)  that "Pip supports editable installs from pyproject.toml files since [21.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v21-3)

> ## Changelog [pip documentation]
>
> ### 21.3 (2021-10-11)
>
> Support editable installs **for projects that have a `pyproject.toml`** and use a build backend that supports [PEP 660](https://peps.python.org/pep-0660/). ([#8212](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8212))

My pip is version 18.1, so that's probably the reason:

```
$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

I'll upgrade my pip and try again... Yes, I [upgraded pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#upgrading-pip) ...

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ pip --version
pip 23.0.1 from c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

and now I could do this workflow:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle.git
$ cd arelle
$ pip install -e .
```

(Maybe I could've used the shortcut recommended on the arelle project:  `pip install git+https://git@github.com/arelle/arelle.git@master` This method failed for me the first time (because "File could not be found!", presumably because of an old version of pip!)

More on python packages here

- [Why site-packages includes two folders for each package](https://py-pkgs.org/04-package-structure.html)