# How to install a package using pip in editable mode with pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

When a project is specified *only* via `pyproject.toml` (i.e. no `setup.{py,cfg}` files), how can it be installed in editable mode via `pip` (i.e. `python -m pip install -e .`)?

I tried both `setuptools` and `poetry` for the build system, but neither worked:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I get the same error for both build systems:

```
ERROR: Project file:///tmp/demo has a 'pyproject.toml' and its build backend is missing the 'build_editable' hook. Since it does not have a 'setup.py' nor a 'setup.cfg', it cannot be installed in editable mode. Consider using a build backend that supports PEP 660.
```

I'm using this inside a `conda` environment, the following is my version of `setuptools` and `pip`:

```
$ conda list | grep setuptools
setuptools                58.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
$ python -m pip --version
pip 21.3.1
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[PEP 660 – Editable installs for pyproject.toml based builds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0660/) defines how to build projects that only use `pyproject.toml`. Build tools must implement PEP 660 for editable installs to work. You need a front-end (such as [pip ≥ 21.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v21-3)) and a backend. The statuses of some popular backends are:

- [Setuptools implements PEP 660 as of version 64.](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#v6400)
- [Flit implements PEP 660 as of version 3.4.](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html?highlight=660#version-3-4)
- [Poetry implements PEP 660 as of version 1.0.8.](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/releases/tag/1.0.8)

**Note:** To be able to do an editable installation to your *user* site (`pip install -e --user`), you need a *system* installed `setuptools` [v62.0.0 or newer](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3019#issuecomment-1264613828).

Comment: Thanks for the good overview and the various suggestions. Eventually I managed to do an editable install via `flit`.

Comment: I find it incredibly confusing that "implements PEP 660" seems to mean "frontend which supports PEP 660-compliant backends". Practically, one needs both the frontend and the backend. The only compliant backend I've been able to find so far is Flit. The Poetry implementation has still not been released. From what I can tell, [pip is just a frontend](https://packaging-the-hard-way.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pep517.html?highlight=frontend#let-pip-build-the-distribution-for-you) There seems to be [no implementation yet for setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2816).

Comment: PEP 660 is implemented in [poetry 1.0.8](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/releases/tag/1.0.8)

Comment: Pip supports editable installs from `pyproject.toml` files since [21.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v21-3)

Comment: Maybe [_hatch_](https://pypi.org/project/hatch/), [_pdm_](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/), and [_whey_](https://pypi.org/project/whey/) could be on this list. As far as I can tell, they are all PEP 660-compatible.

Comment: Setuptools is working on it! Yet to be merged into main, but the functionality is being implemented on [this branch](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/tree/feature/pep660)

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2816 is now merged. would be good to know how to use setuptooks with editable install hook in pyproject.toml

Comment: To avoid the "system installed setuptools" requirement, you can do a non-isolated build as well (e.g., with `--no-build-isolation`)

Comment: @Eric's answer worked for me after I followed the accepted answer. The command was `pip install -e . --no-build-isolation` where as `pip install -e --user` kept giving me the error **ERROR: --user is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh,
 bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+htt
p, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file)**

Answer (score 71):

I stumbled here as I searched for the error string "`(A "pyproject.toml" file was found, but editable mode currently requires a setuptools-based build.)`"

In my case, all I needed to do was update pip:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then the install worked fine.

Answer (score 25):

***Note**: This workaround is no longer required. Setuptools supports editable installations since [v64.0.0](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v64-0-0) (Aug 2022). Old answer remains below for people stuck on older setuptools versions for whatever reason...*

As a temporary workaround until setuptools implements PEP 660 ([#2816](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2816)) you can create an empty setup file just for the purpose of the editable installation.

```
touch setup.cfg
pip install -e .
rm setup.cfg
```

*Note*: this is not actually invoking any `build_editable` hook (which doesn't even exist in setuptools' backend currently), instead it triggers a code path within pip which creates a temporary `setup.py` and then executes `setup.py develop`. So it's a "legacy" editable installation, done by putting down a link to the source code in a [path configuration file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) like `.venv/lib/python3.XY/site-packages/easy-install.pth`. Poetry and flit do similar, except they're creating separate path files like `mypkg.pth` in the site dir, rather than using lines in `easy-install.pth`.

Because `setup.py develop` is a path file hack, the usual caveats of such development installs apply, e.g. it exposes any .py files which happen to be present in the source directory even if they are not actually packaged into a real distribution when creating a release.

Comment: Thanks! It does seem to work, but why? Do you have any explanation at hand?

Comment: See how [pip checks whether the build backend supports editable installation](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/22.1.1/src/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py#L483-L502)

Answer (score 2):

As of poetry 1.2.0b3, "current project" is automatically installed in editable mode by default when you run `poetry install`.

```bash
$ pip uninstall virtualenv # or via apt if you installed that way
$ sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools
$ wget install.python-poetry.org -o get-poetry.py
$ python3 get-poetry.py --preview
$ cd /you/project/folder
$ poetry install
$ pip list
Package            Version  Editable project location
------------------ -------- -------------------------------------------
...
your-project       0.1.0    /you/project/folder
pip                22.2.2
...
```

Answer (score -3):

Found a great resource here:

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#development-mode

```
pip install --editable .
```